# Авторизация не работает

Tags: php, авторизация

Ошибок не выдает, но и не выводит echo

```
    // ПРОВЕРКА
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$connect = mysqli_connect ("localhost","root","vertrigo","my_bd");
if (!$connect) {
    mysqli_error();
}

if (isset($_POST['enter'])) {
    $enter_login = $_POST['enter_login'];
    $enter_pswd = md5($_POST['enter_pswd']);
    $sql = mysqli_query($connect, " SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'login' = '$enter_login' ");
    $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);

    if ($user_data['password'] == $enter_pswd) {
        echo 'HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO HELLO'; 
    }
}

mysqli_close($connect);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена! Была допущена ошибка в синтаксисе:

Так правильно:
$sql = mysqli_query($connect,  " SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = '$enter_login' ");

Так не правильно:
$sql = mysqli_query($connect,  " SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'login' = '$enter_login' ");

Answer (score 1):

Если ничего не выводится значит соединение с базой есть, но не выполняется условие 
 `if ($user_data['password'] == $enter_pswd)`

 попробуйте перед проверкой (выражение которое написано выше) вывести две переменные и посмотреть что в них лежит 
 `echo $user_data['password']` 
 `echo $enter_pswd`

Comment: мало данных, но обрати внимание , что после пароль, которое приходит с формы, обрабатывается функцией md5, а в Вашей бд в каком виде хранится пароль?

Comment: убрал везде md5, выве перед проверкой два пароля: echo $user_data['password']
echo $enter_pswd, из которых $user_data['password'] просто не выводиться. Другой который мы вводим в форму выводит.

Comment: + попробовал создать юзера через phpmyadmin такая же ситуация, хотел проверить может данные не правильно передаються при регестрации

Comment: Надо пользоваться документацией. функция mysqli_query() возвращает false в случаи неудачи, если запрос отработал вернет result, а для все остальных случаев вернет тру. Следовательно , попробуйте вот так написать: <br/> `echo $sql = mysqli_query($connect, " SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'login' = '$enter_login' ");` и посмотреть результат, сразу станет понятно в чем проблема

Comment: Ошибка: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string.

Comment: хорошо, значит все таки данные с базы выбираются

Comment: Что же делать? Я только учусь уже 3 день не понимаю как нужно исправить.

Comment: давай дальше пошагово `$user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo "<pre>";
print_f($user_data);
echo "</pre>";`

Comment: Ошибка: Call to undefined function print_f(). Ели  $user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql); echo "<pre>"; print($user_data); echo "</pre>"; Тогда просто ничего не выводит

Comment: извини , я неправильно написал команду, printf должно быть..но и принт тоже должен был что либо вывести....попробй этой же командой вывести переменную sql после обращения к базе

Comment: и еще покажи файл с формой то что написано в теге form

Comment: <form action="index.php" method="post">
   <h1>Войдите пожалуйста:</h1>
   <input type="text" name="enter_login" required placeholder=" | Login" class="enter_input"><br>
   <input type="password" name="enter_pswd" required placeholder=" | Password" class="enter_input"><br>

   <input type="submit" name="enter" value="Войти" class="enter_input">
  </form>

Comment: я бы тебе посоветовал по выводить все переменные на экран после того как отправил форму на обработку, и смотреть что выводится и так пошагово выяснить в чем причина

Comment: хорошо попробую

Answer (score 0):

Добавьте строку с выводом отладочной информации и всё станет ясно.

```
$user_data = mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
echo $user_data['password'], ' - ', $enter_pswd;  // ДОБАВИТЬ ЭТУ СТРОКУ
if ($user_data['password'] == $enter_pswd) {
```

**И ещё**

```
$sql = mysqli_query($connect, " SELECT * FROM users WHERE 'login' = '$enter_login' ");
```

[SQL-injection](https://habrahabr.ru/post/148151/)